# How can I evaluate a senior developer when I'm not a developer?

Tags: interviewing

I want to recruit a Senior PHP developer, and a Senior UI developer. The problem is that I am not a developer, thus I can't really evaluate their programming ability myself.

How can I accurately gauge the technical capabilities of potential candidates for these roles?

Comment: You might find these two questions on Startups interesting: https://startups.stackexchange.com/q/3199/1824 and https://startups.stackexchange.com/q/3112/1824

Comment: even if there was an exercise or a riddle, how would you grade the answer. There are often many answers to the same question in programming.

Comment: @SaggingRufus A few coding challenge sites score the algorithm you've written in terms of correctness and efficiency. Although whether this is available to use for interviews, how to interpret the result and whether that's accurate or a good measure of ability for a developer is another story entirely.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere GREAT POINT.  How can you manage someone where you cannot measure the resources throughput effectively?

Comment: why is this question downvoted??? this is, i think, a good question, no?

Comment: @bharal Well, because this question is primarily opinion based.  ;-)

Comment: @MisterPositive disagree - "what is the best ice cream flavour" is primarily opinion based. this question can be answered with a process, and while there might be disagreements on the *best* process, a process will exist.

Comment: @bharal You do not have to agree.  The community has spoken, and will speak again if this question is re-opened.  That is my favorite part of this community.

Comment: @Dukeling edit is enough to have it reopened IMO, I casted my close vote before the edit.

Answer (score 16):

> How do I test a senior developer when I'm not a developer?

You don't.

> How do I accurately gauge a candidates technical capabilities?

If you don't have the relevant background, then you may not be in a position to gauge a candidate's technical ability.

So have someone else do it.

If you have other Developers or someone else who has the right experience on the team who are capable, ask them to handle the technical aspects while you handle other aspects.

If you have nobody at all, you may need to bring in a consultant to help with the sourcing and hiring of the Developers. HR, if you have one, can help find a consultant. Lacking HR, your Board of Directors can help find a consultant.

This holds true for any role (Developer, Sales, Accounting, etc) for which you don't have the relevant expertise. Find someone else who does to aid in the interviews.

Comment: This is a chicken-egg problem. You can not tell which consultants have the relevant expertise when you can not judge expertise.

Comment: @Philipp Your right to an extent, but in the OP's position, they have to trust the judgement of someone.....

Comment: alternatively OP can hire from a known company, which might not solve the problem extremely well but is better than nothing.

Comment: @bharal Hiring from a known company is not usually feasible.  Companies with real senior developers know what they have and take good care of their resources.  YMMV

Comment: @bharal I have seen people with title in known company that weren't technically competent. Even if they title suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

When you don't have technical skills yourself, then judging technical skill is pretty much impossible. Automatized and standardized tests might be useful to weed out the total frauds. But those questions which really tell you the difference between a mediocre developer and a top developer are questions which have no one right answer. Without technical expertise there is no way to judge them properly.

What you can do instead is estimate their skills by looking at past projects and references. Ask to see some projects they did before which are similar to what you want them to do. You can also ask people who did similar projects in the past if they can recommend you someone.

But keep in mind that **programming skill is not the only thing which is important for a developer**. One essential skill, for example, is being able to communicate properly. Even more so when you lack technical know-how yourself. Some developers might be absolute geniuses when it comes to solving technical problems, but they fail when it comes to explaining these problems and their solution to a technical layman like you. If you look for [top reason why IT projects fail](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=reasons+why+it+projects+fail), you will rarely find "lack of technical expertise". Most can be summarized as "management and team failed to communicate properly".

This is something you can actually test. First make sure they are aware that you are not a technical person, so they realize they need to use appropriate language. Then ask them what their most difficult problem was in their last project and how they solved it. Listen to their explanation.

Is it just technobabble to you? That's a bad sign. They seem to lack the communication skills to explain their work in a way that you can understand it. That will become a problem in the long-run, because you can not manage them when you can not communicate with them.

But do you feel like you actually understood the problem and the solution despite your lack of knowledge? Do you maybe even learned something new from it? Then they might be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Having been though one of these so called tests myself, I would suggest you **abandon the whole notion of testing** a senior developer.  I would spend much more time on work ethic, team compatibility, and willingness to share their knowledge.

> Are there online testing resources (e.g. Mocha Interview) that make
>   sense or should I give the candidates a small project?

As an experienced technical interviewer, you should be able to get a feel if a developer your interviewing is really "senior" by asking them key questions related to your ( *and their* ) tech stack, and you should also be able to gauge this by his previous work experience ( A combination of titles, time on the job, and projects ).  **If you are not technical**, then you should *obtain assistance from another resource on your team for the technical evaluation*.

> How do I accurately gauge a candidates technical capabilities?

The bottom line IMHO is that a test is simply that, a test that reflects one part of a candidates capabilities.  The only way you will really know if a person is who they say they are is if you give them a shot.

Comment: I agree, also some people just don't test well. I know people who are great technicians, but terrible test writers. They focus WAY too much on what they think you want rather than what the solution is.

Comment: @SaggingRufus That would be **me** to a fault.  My track record and linkedin recommendations are a far better gauge of my capabilities.  YMMV

Comment: disagree... how do you know someone is capable if you just talk about culture fit? unless OP is hiring from a known company (google, goldman etc)

Comment: @bharal You look at their experience.  You discuss the technical stack you will expect this person to use, and you talk to some folks who have worked with them in the past.  Get recommendations.  Anyone can get lucky and "pass" a so called test.....

Comment: Also when you do the reference check you can ask to speak with someone technical and ask if their skills are as good as they say they are

Comment: @SaggingRufus Good point.  I also looked at LinkedIn recommendations.

Comment: @MisterPositive i'm sorry, i don't see any good in asking people you don't know if someone is reliable. lot of people saying "they don't test well" - well, they should get better at it. just like some people "don't interview well" or "don't drive well" or "don't do their job well" - its your responsibility to work and improve yourself. If you're hiring, you want someone who puts effort in to everything,

Comment: @bharal I don't dispute the usefulness of testing in most cases.  As a developer there are many ways to solve a problem, and usually there are multiple GOOD ways to solve an issue.  How do you test for that?  Testing for developers doesn't make a lot of sense based on my experience as a tech hiring person.  YMMV ( on a side note don't be sorry for your opinion )

Comment: @bharal it is something the candidate needs to work on, but would you pass up a good candidate because they didn't test well? If I was hiring in a field I had no idea about, I would heavily rely on the reference check and be sure to use my probation period wisely. You can usually tell if someone if full of crap by asking to explain what they are talking about. People who are just using buzz words will fall off quickly.

Comment: @bharal And "don't test well" most definitely does not mean "doesn't perform well on the job"

Comment: @MisterPositive well, there are two problems when hiring. 1 - are you hiring for problem solving or for skills? If you're hiring based on "ability to solve problems" then you *need* to invest in training. If you're - which is the easier of the two to do, because you can test for this- if you're hiring for skills, then you need to be aware you might not be hiring people who will think outside the box. It's rare you find both in one person.

Comment: @MisterPositive most companies spend somewhere close to zero on training, so they don't get to make use of the best problem solvers. And while "doesn't test well" doesn't make or break job performance, it also doesn't guarantee good job performance either - you're more likely to find a solid performer from the set of people who tested well than from the set who didn't.

Comment: @bharal Do you have and data to back up that statement?

Comment: @MisterPositive which one? the one about test budget, or the one about job performance vs test results?

Comment: @bharal Your last statement.  I have seen many times where a guy can talk the talk, take the test, and SUCK HORRIBLY in the actual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating this level of developer in your situation can be tricky, but not because of the level of their skills. If you are expected to hire Senior Developers and are asking this question (no offense) your technical environment must not be too large or complex. If it were, it would seem there should be processes in place for this already. If this is the case, as a non-technical manager you are in a rough spot - you will be working from faith and trust in your hire, not your ability to make informed decisions based on what they say and do.

You may want to ask yourself if you are ready to hire yet. Do you have a clear definition of these roles? I.e., do you have requirements, architectures, designs, etc. and need developers to realize them or do you have a "need" and expect these two do start from ground zero. A developer and an architect are two different things. Even a programmer and developer can be different things - which do you need?

Not knowing your situation, it may make more sense to hire an Architect with strong hands-on skills. Once the design is complete, let them help find the best (depending on budget) programmers to realize that vision.

Also, "Testing" a Senior Developer is a waste of time, and it's also insulting. As you become more Senior you also become more specialized or removed from "101" level things, but most canned tests are at the "101" level. If you've been architecting complex systems for the last 15 years you probably haven't been solving many array manipulation puzzles. These days, it is expected that a developer (looking for a job) have a "portfolio". The most basic expectation is a GitHub repository. This substitutes for any "test", which should be reserved for entry-level to <2-year developers. Think about your job. If you've spent 15 years in your position and someone asked to take a test that was like a sophomore midterm, how would you feel?

Answer (score 0):

Are you the only one doing the interview?  If that's the case then you should reconsider and add technical expertise to the interview team.

In cases like this you would have current developers evaluate the technical portion of any interviews.

You would handle the non-technical aspects of interviews.  The oft-overused term 'soft skills'.

I would not be comfortable being the sole interviewer for a requirement that requires technical skills unless I have a knowledge of those technical skills.